# pug file, to connect to Websocket, and then display values arriving?

Tags: css, node.js, websocket, real-time-updates

Here's a simple pug file

```
p Hello
```

The backend is ordinary node, express, passport, sql so something like

```
app.get('/example', (request, response) => {
  response.render('example.pug');
})
```

I want the web page to

1. Connect to a websocket server
2. Any text that arrives, simply display that where the 'Hello' is

How to do this?

(So, TBC the server looks something like this ... I can easily do that end of it.)

```
function sendInfoToAnyBrowserConnected() {
    connections.forEach(function tell(c) {
        if (c.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) {
            c.send("this text gets displayed")
```

What should I put in my pug file?

Answer (score 0):

I've had to figure it out myself - damn you, SO!  Essentially this

```
<a id="log" size=10></a>
```

with this

```
var el = document.getElementById("log");
```

and this

```
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML + "<br>" + e.data;
```

and that's it.

So in total basically

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function VanillaData() {
        var ws = new WebSocket("ws://ws.yours.com:2345");

        ws.onopen = function() { ws.send("from www ,v1"); };

        ws.onmessage = function(e) {
            el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML + "<br>" + e.data;
        };

        ws.onclose = function() { console.log("ws closed..."); };
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
Your live stuff:
<br>
<a id="log" size=10></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var el = document.getElementById("log");
    VanillaData()
</script>
</body >
</html >
```

I'm not knowledgeable about pug, so cannot comment on how the .pug file should look.

Using an online html-pug convertor, this does work:

```
head
  script(type='text/javascript').
    function VanillaData() {
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://you.com:2345");
    ws.onopen = function() { ws.send("from www"); };
    ws.onmessage = function(e) {
    el.innerHTML = e.data + "<br>" + el.innerHTML;
    };
    ws.onclose = function() { console.log("ws closed ..."); };
    }
| Live stuff:
br
pre#log(size='10').

script(type='text/javascript').
  var el = document.getElementById("log");
  VanillaData()
```

Seems to work great.